# If input is empty add value jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem because I would like to make it so that when the `customernamemulti` is empty it will add to `Applying_credit_value` a 1000 to the field if not 2000 (then I would like to add e.g. requeired) I also tried to add . length but it didn't help either.

EDITED ( add trigger)
Here is my source code:
https://jsfiddle.net/Palucci92/h2rn3b06/21/

```js
var tableOutstandingBalanceRowCount = ($('#Insurer_information tr').length) - 2;

for (i = 0; i < tableOutstandingBalanceRowCount; i++) {
  var customernamemulti = $('[id^="customernamemulti');

  if (customernamemulti.val().length === 0) {
    $('[id^="Applying_credit_value').val(1000)
  } 
  else if (customernamemult.val().length != 0) {
    $('[id^="Applying_credit_value').val(2000)
  }
}
```

Comment: but when should it fill that? you didn't define any trigger

Comment: ahh so should i add on change ?

Comment: May be, key up ,  change, focousout  ever thing applied here as per your requirement, you must call that for loop some where .

Comment: Off topic / your next issue: if you have a single element with an ID (and you should, IDs must be unique) then use `$("#customernamemulti")`.    Your js *implies* there's more than one, but `$('[id^="customernamemulti').val()` will *still* only get the first one.  You need to loop the `tr`s you get and then get the elements *within* that tr: `$('#Insurer_information tr').each(function() { $(this).find(".customernamemulti")...`.   If you have a change event, then use `this` for the input and relative DOM navigation, eg `var $tr = $(this).closest("tr")`

Comment: Guys, i added on change but still not working . @freedomn-m i added id^ beacuase i  will have a dynamic table with indexing input [0], [1]

Comment: `$('[id^="customernamemulti').val()` will still only get the first one, so even if your IDs are unique but have the same prefix, this *will still get the first one*

Comment: please check for syntax errors in your new code, you got red dots with unmatched brackets